# Z-index of nested elements

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I have a problem with usage of z-index in nested elements.
I try to create a interactive introduction tutorial for my site (using library Trip.js)
The problem appears by "highlighting" of particular elements.

The approach to highlighting is following: 
First for "fading" the whole site content an overlay is created. It gets some opacity and z-index = 3, to cover all the elements of the site.
Than the element, which should be highlighted gets dynamically z-index = 4, so it should be shown in front of the overlay.

The problem is that this element could be contained in another element which has position = 'relative' and z-index = 2. So even if I set position = 'absolute' to highlighted element, it is still shown behind the overlay, because z-index of parent element if lower than z-index of overlay.

I have access to style of the highlighted element and the overlay, but unfortunately access to parent element in generic way is nearly impossible (since it is generated by other library, could be nested multiple times to other elements with their own style etc.)

So is there any way to force the highlighted element to be shown in front of the overlay regardless of parent elements style?

Comment: could you create a  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your query.

Comment: I do not think it's possible although will love to see a solution with just CSS